# Nested loops with depth parameter in python

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

How do I make a number of nested loops where depth is a parameter. 
I am thinking of a function which takes depth as a parameter

```
def make_nested_loops(depth):
    ...
```

And, the result for `depth=3` is the following

```
for i1 in range(10):
    for i2 in range(i1 + 1, 10):
        for i3 in range(i2 + 1, 10):
            # do stuff
```

So far I've been able to do this using strings building and `exec` command. But I think there is better and more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Nested loops create a larger complexity.  What is it you're looping through and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why? The inner loops *depend* on the containing loops, so you can't really flatten it.

Comment: By the way, what is `make_nested_loops` supposed to return? A loop isn't an object, it's a syntactic construct. Perhaps it should take a second argument that is a function to call that receives a tuple `(i1, i2, ...)` as an argument and is called where `#do stuff` occurs.

Comment: @chepner It is supposed to return a list or a dictionary of tuples, where each tuple's length is exactly the depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inefficient but simple approach would be to use `itertools.product` and filter unwanted tuples:

```
def make_tuples(depth, n):
    for i in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=depth):
        if sorted(i) < i:
            continue
        yield i
```

More efficient would be a recursive generator:

```
def make_tuples(depth, n, start=0):
    if depth == 0:
        yield ()
    else:
        for x in range(start, n):
            for t in make_tuples(depth - 1, n, x + 1):
                yield (x,) + t
```

Using it would look like

```
for (i1, i2, i3) in make_tuples(3, 10):
    # do stuff with i1, i2, i3
```

If the depth is *really* dynamic, you can't of course unpack the tuples coming from `make_tuples`. The body will have to know what to do with tuples
of fixed but unknown length.

```
for tpl in make_tuples(n, 10):
    # Do stuff with tpl
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @chepner

Answer (score 1):

The max number of nested loops you can have is 21 I think. So what you could do is have 21 nested loops in your function, and check if desired depth has been achieved at each loop. If not, add one to current depth variable.

Comment: "The max number of nested loops you can have is 21" Source please?

Comment: @Rightleg I think she may be right. I checked [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue986720) and one of the author's said 20 is  the max. I'm still not 100% sure though and I'm still looking.

Comment: @ChristianDean Well I just tested and that's right, 19 works but 20 does not. For the record, it fails with `SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks`. But I do want a source.

Comment: Actually I cannot upvote this answer as it is not a good answer to the question, but I want to thank for letting me know that Python had such a limitation.

Comment: My source is experience, I once tried to make a ton of nested loops and it crashed with more than 19.

Comment: @Rightleg of course recursion would be a better solution, but the question asked for how to do it with nested loops so that is what I gave

Comment: I took the liberty to ask a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972719/increase-the-number-of-statically-nested-block). If you happen to have more details, please share them with us.