# Why does Python have a limit on the number of static blocks that can be nested?

Tags: python, nested-loops, language-implementation

The number of statically nested blocks in Python is limited to 20.
That is, nesting 19 `for` loops will be fine (although excessively time consuming; `O(n^19)` is insane), but nesting 20 will fail with:

```
SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks
```

What is the underlying reason for having such a limit?
Is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: Why do you want to increase this? Is this a practical issue for you?

Comment: I am still wondering about the relevance of this in real life. I would assume that hitting this limit is only possible with insane spaghetti code. Or what am I missing here?

Comment: @GhostCat Two words: autogenerated code.

Comment: @Jason The same limit should apply to nested `if`s. 20 nested `if`s are a less contrived example than 20 nested `for`s. The "excessively time consuming" argument does not apply to them.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This limit not only applies to `for` loops, but to all other control flow blocks as well. The limit for the number of nested control flow blocks is defined inside of [code.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Include/code.h#L95) with a constant named `CO_MAXBLOCKS`:

```c
#define CO_MAXBLOCKS 20 /* Max static block nesting within a function */
```

This constant is used to set the maximum size for the stack Python uses to execute exceptions and loops named `blockstack`. This limit is imposed upon all frame objects and is shown in [frameobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/frameobject.c#L82):

```c
int blockstack[CO_MAXBLOCKS];       /* Walking the 'finally' blocks */
```

The most likely reason for this limit is to keep memory usage at a sane level when executing nested blocks. It's probably similar to [the limit Python imposes on recursive calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it). This limit can be seen being enforced in [compile.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c#L4708):

```c
if (c->u->u_nfblocks >= CO_MAXBLOCKS) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SyntaxError,
                    "too many statically nested blocks");
    return 0;
}
```

A more concrete answer as to why Python has this specfic limit and why they cannot get rid of it, was given by [Michael Hudson in a 2004 Python mailing list letter](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-July/288790.html):

> Spot on.  This has to do with the 'blockstack', very much an internal
>   detail to Python's implementation.  We'd like to get rid of it (*not*
>   because we want to let people write code with more than 20 nested for
>   loops :-) but it's not especially easy (finally: blocks are the
>   biggest problem).

Note that in Python 2.6 and lower, breaking the maximum number of nested loops would've cause a `SystemError` not a `SyntaxError`. This was changed however  in Python 3 and back-patched to Python 2.7 so a `SyntaxError` would be raised instead. This was documented in [#issue 27514](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4baacee1adc06edbe30ac7574d17a8cd168e2e0/Misc/NEWS#L2783):

> Issue #27514: Make having too many statically nested blocks a SyntaxError
>     instead of SystemError.

The reason for this change in exception types was given by [Serhiy Storchaka](https://bugs.python.org/msg270409) :

> [...] SystemError is not an exception that should be raised. SystemError is for errors that can't be occurred in normal case. It should only be caused by incorrect use of C API or hacking Python internals. I think SyntaxError is more appropriate in this case [...].

Comment: So the solution (which no-one is recommending) for the problem (that no-one actually has) is to hack the CPython source code?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yup, I guess so. If you change `CO_MAXBLOCKS` then recompile, I guess you could have more than twenty nested blocks in theory.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I didn't see that, but the test suites would likely complain too https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ea4186de32d65b1f1dc1533b6312b798d300466/Lib/test/test_sys.py#L996 and  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/test/test_syntax.py#L372

Comment: @Chris_Rands I do believe you can make build without make tests, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Rightleg Thanks. I had fun writing this answer. To be honest, I never knew Python had this limit. I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 25):

This has to do with the [`blockstack`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/frameobject.c#L82), which is a stack of the byte code addresses, and is used to execute code blocks such as loops and exceptions.

It just so happens that a version of C (older than C99) had set this limit to `20`, and since the CPython interpreter is built with C, [the same convention has been followed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Include/code.h#L95):

```c
#define CO_MAXBLOCKS 20 /* Max static block nesting within a function */
```

The constant `20` seems to be set out of convention, and nothing more.

[Links courtesy Christian Dean.]

---

#### Why is the limit 20?

If the argument of convention isn't convincing, then take a look at *The Zen of Python*:

```
In [4]: import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

...
Flat is better than nested.
...
```

---

#### How can you increase this value?

Since this value is a hardcoded constant, the only way to change it to effect in your programs is to rebuild your python distribution and run your script on the new build.

1. Download the cpython source code from [github](https://github.com/python/cpython)
2. Navigate to `cpython/Include/code.h`
3. Change the value of `CO_MAXBLOCKS` to anything greater than 20
4. Recompile Python (disable tests, [they'll complain](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/test/test_syntax.py#L372))

Comment: You know, C99 (The one standard I found just now) allows a minimum of 127 levels of nesting. That's a bit more than 20. And GCC for example goes for "whatever we have the resources to compile" anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yep, I did see that was the limit for C99. This is more of a convention than out of any imposed restriction except memory limits.

Comment: Actually the number 20 makes some sense to me, it's not completely random: the recommended settings are 4 spaces for indentation, and 80 characters per line. And 80/4 = 20.

Comment: [ANSI C](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) doesn't set the nesting limit to 20, either. It is 15 for "compound statements, iteration control structures, and selection control structures". So, the level of 20 had to be chosen for a later C standard that had a higher limit, and it was (as you already stated) chosen rather arbitrarily.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for clarifying that. I never really found any official source for that information, just discussions in various forums.

Answer (score 4):

See answer here: [too many statically nested blocks python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470536/too-many-statically-nested-blocks-python)
You cannot increase it as it is builtin to the python syntax. The limit applies to any kind of code stack (exceptions, loops, etc.) and is a decision by the designers (presumably to keep memory usage reasonable).
One weird thing is that here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Include/code.h#L95 it says 20 is the max number *in a function*. But I just tried nesting 23 for loops, not inside a function, and you still get the error.

Comment: I suppose that *in a function* just means that if you call another function at level 20, that one still can nest 20 deep.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense