# Hello World in Python: fatal block stack overflow?

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to implement a simple Hello World program in Python. The following code prints "Hello World" just fine:

```py
def main(data=[72, 29, 7, 0, 3, -79, 55, 24, 3, -6, -8]):
    print(chr(data[0]), end="")
    if len(data) > 1:
        data[0] += data.pop(1)
        raise Exception()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                main()
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    main()
                except Exception as e:
                    try:
                        main()
                    except Exception as e:
                        try:
                            main()
                        except Exception as e:
                            try:
                                main()
                            except Exception as e:
                                try:
                                    main()
                                except Exception as e:
                                    try:
                                        main()
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        try:
                                            main()
                                        except Exception as e:
                                            main()
```

...but when I try to add an exclamation point at the end, like this:

```
def main(data=[72, 29, 7, 0, 3, -79, 55, 24, 3, -6, -8, -67]):
    if len(data) > 1:
        data[0] += data.pop(1)
        raise Exception()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                main()
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    main()
                except Exception as e:
                    try:
                        main()
                    except Exception as e:
                        try:
                            main()
                        except Exception as e:
                            try:
                                main()
                            except Exception as e:
                                try:
                                    main()
                                except Exception as e:
                                    try:
                                        main()
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        try:
                                            main()
                                        except Exception as e:
                                            try:
                                                main()
                                            except Exception as e:
                                                main()
```

...I get a `Fatal Python error: XXX block stack overflow`.

I've tried adding more try/except clauses to catch the block stack overflow error, but nothing seems to work. What the heck is the block stack, and why would such a straightforward approach not work?

Comment: "straightforward approach"?

Comment: Maybe you intended to post this as an April Fool's Day joke in which case you're a day early

Comment: Well you certainly caught on that it was a joke :-) although I figured not a completely uninteresting question. But man, I really should have waited till april fools day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue39934) that's been "fixed". However, it's more the exact error message, and nesting depth limit, that changed. Python doesn't really intend to support arbitrarily deep static nesting. It would if doing so were trivial, but [it's not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972719/why-does-python-have-a-limit-on-the-number-of-static-blocks-that-can-be-nested). Rather than "a straightforward approach", I expect most programmers would consider such deep nesting to be "a nightmare" ;-)

Comment: Very interesting links that totally explain the situation! Interesting that `except Exception as e` is actually implicitly creating extra layers of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.10 I get an error message that's more self-explanatory:

```
    try:
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks
```

You delved too greedily, and too deep.  Restructure the code to not have this many blocks nested inside of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that you're trying to experiment with and understand exception handling in Python. Perhaps this will help:

```
def main(data=[72, 29, 7, 0, 3, -79, 55, 24, 3, -6, -8, -67]):
    print(chr(data[0]), end="")
    if len(data) > 1:
        data[0] += data.pop(1)
        raise Exception()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            main()
            # when the *data* list contains only one element
            # main() will implicitly return None - i.e., no exception
            break
        except Exception:
            pass
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world!
```

Having said that, your code could be simplified as:

```
def main(data=[72, 29, 7, 0, 3, -79, 55, 24, 3, -6, -8, -67]):
    print(chr(data[0]), end="")
    data[0] += data.pop(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            main()
        except IndexError:
            break
```

Comment: Good suggestions for improvement. Although I suppose it could even be further simplified to `print("Hello world!")` Why didn't I think of that?